# Building a converter app

Tags: java, android

Ok, so I am brand new to this, I am trying to build a converter app for android using android studio, without the use of buttons. I am able to use OnFocusChangeListener to convert, say inches to centimeters without a button, but what I am really looking to do is put inches in the editText field, and have centimeters populate automatically, and vice versa, I really need to do this with more than 2 fields at the same time, say input inches, and centimeters, meters, feet, yards, etc, or be able to input to any one of those fields and have the others auto populate, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you could use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to implement this. It allows you to monitor the changements in the current `EditText` you type in.

So you will have to implement the method [`onTextChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (or `afterTextChanged`, depends on your needs).

Let's say you write in the `EditText` where you enter the inches. In the `onTextChanged` method you would update the other fiels with the right conversion.

You will find several tutorials/example on the web.